# Get the ID of a record in a gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a checkbox in a template field of a gridview and i want to get the id of the record at a checkbox tick. how do i do it? i am doing asp.net and  also by using datakeynames instead, my gridview also shows the datakeynames persID column. why?

my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHostelMember" runat="server" DataKeyNames="_PersID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="_PersID" HeaderText="_PersID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FatherName" HeaderText="FatherName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow item in this.GridViewHostelMember.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chbTemp = item.FindControl("CheckBoxSelect") as CheckBox;
        if (chbTemp != null)
        {
            if (chbTemp.Checked)
            {
                Label1.Text = item.Cells[0].Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_PersID is showing because autogeneratecolumns is set to true; if true, it shows all columns.  To hide, set to false, and explicitly add the columns to the grid.

For the first part, at checkbox tick, you would need to set `AutoPostBack="true"` on the checkbox, which posts back, and then you can check the data key for the current row of the grid.

Comment: _PersID is showing because autogeneratecolumns is set to true; if true, it shows all columns. To hide, set to false, and explicitly add the columns to the grid.

it`s still showing. :/

Comment: Can you then update your grid definition so I can look at it and see?

Comment: well yea sure.. sorry for replying late here

Comment: @AbidAli _PersID will show because it has a column in the grid: `<asp:BoundField DataField="_PersID" HeaderText="_PersID" />` (remove this)

Answer (score 1):

**[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)** -

> my gridview also shows the datakeynames persID column. why?

---

> true to automatically create bound fields for each field in the data
>   source; otherwise, false. The default is true.

It should be like below..

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHostelMember" autogeneratecolumns="False" 
                               runat="server" DataKeyNames="_PersID">
```

---

> i want to get the id of the record at a checkbox tick. how do i do it?

### Sample Code

```
protected void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)sender;
    //c.ValidationGroup is your ID
}
```

### Sample HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="ed" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ValidationGroup='<%#Eval("ID") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_Checked"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```